# Spring-WS with Boot not working after jar packaging

Tags: gradle, spring-boot

My project is split into several modules:

A submodule that contains the actual web service.

Several modules that depend on the submodule and define their own @SpringBootApplication classes:

```
version '1.0'

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.4.0.RELEASE")
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':submodule')
}

jar {
    baseName = 'jarfilename'
}
```

The problem is now that the classes generated by the submodule's JAXB task are not accessible when the jar file is run:

```
javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: "bws.wsdl" doesnt contain ObjectFactory.class or jaxb.index
        at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
        at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:171) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
        at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:131) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
        ... 31 common frames omitted
```

The project runs fine from the IDE (Intellij Idea).

The submodule's build.gradle looks like this:

```
version '1.0'

apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

configurations {
    jaxb
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

// tag::wsdl[]
task genJaxb {
    ext.sourcesDir = "${buildDir}/generated-sources/jaxb"
    ext.classesDir = "${buildDir}/classes/jaxb"
    ext.schema = "path-to-wsdl.xml"
    outputs.dir classesDir

    doLast() {
        project.ant {
            taskdef name: "xjc", classname: "com.sun.tools.xjc.XJCTask",
                    classpath: configurations.jaxb.asPath
            mkdir(dir: sourcesDir)
            mkdir(dir: classesDir)

            xjc(destdir: sourcesDir, schema: schema,
                    package: "wsdl") {
                arg(value: "-wsdl")
                produces(dir: sourcesDir, includes: "**/*.java")
            }

            javac(destdir: classesDir, source: 1.8, target: 1.8, debug: true,
                    debugLevel: "lines,vars,source",
                    classpath: configurations.jaxb.asPath) {
                src(path: sourcesDir)
                include(name: "**/*.java")
                include(name: "*.java")
            }

            copy(todir: classesDir) {
                fileset(dir: sourcesDir, erroronmissingdir: false) {
                    exclude(name: "**/*.java")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile(files(genJaxb.classesDir).builtBy(genJaxb))

    jaxb "com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-xjc:2.1.7"
}

task afterEclipseImport {
    dependsOn genJaxb
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I simply forgot to include the generated classes:

```
jar {
    baseName = 'jarfilename'
    from "${rootDir}/submodule/build/classes/jaxb"
}
```